# (matlab)implement "Evaluate or Open Code You Select" in everywhere?

Tags: matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you retrieve the selected text in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533074/how-do-you-retrieve-the-selected-text-in-matlab)

I want to implement and add some features to the function "Evaluate Selections", where you can highlight code and then "Evaluate Selections" by right click your mouse (or F9).

In the editor environment, this is how it is done:

```
editorObject = matlab.desktop.editor.getActive;
eval([editorObject.SelectedText ';']);
```

How can I implement this from the command line window, or the help window?

**EDIT**:

Maybe I didn't express my question clearly.

Imagining that we already have this function called **eva_select()**, I can use function this way:

1. I wrap the function as the Shortcuts button.
2. Use mouse to **select** a variable at command line window, maybe I entered before, say **var_a**
3. Then I click that Shortcuts button, the text which I selected before will be executed. This is exactly as press **F9** key or choose right mouse menu -- "Evaluate Selections".

**But** if we really have that function, we can do more! We can modified eva_select() to eva_select_**size**(), in this way, we can select a variable, say **var_a** at command line window or help window, click eva_select_size() shortcuts button, then, we will get **size(var_a)** at command line window!

**EDIT**:

Thanks, I can retrieve the text in the command window, but I can't do the same thing in the **help window**, is it possible to do that?

Comment: What kind of features would you like to add? I cannot believe that nate answered what you meant ;-)

Comment: Thanks, @Hugues, I edit my question again to express more clearly ;-)

Comment: it looks like you found a solution with the shortcuts? Or what is it you actually want from there on? gui integration of those extra functions (perhaps in a menu)? Modify the existing "evaluate selection" behaviour?

Comment: @YuHao I'm shocked...Hey!

Answer (score 3):

The command window, like other GUI components in the MATLAB desktop, is Java-based. Therefore it can be accessed programmatically, but it is completely [undocumented](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/) and its use is not officially supported.

Exploring around, here is a solution that seems to work in both R2012a and R2012b. It involves obtaining a handle to the underlying `JTextArea` of the command window, which is used to get the selected text (to evaluate size of selected variable name)

Create a shortcut with the following code:

```
x = com.mathworks.mde.cmdwin.XCmdWndView.getInstance();
s = char(x.getSelectedText());
if isvarname(s) && exist(s,'var')
    eval( sprintf('size(%s)',s) );
end
```

Next highlight a variable name in the command window and execute the shortcut. The size will be immediately printed as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You may want to ensure that you do not accidentally overwrite an exsting variable x or s when using this in a shortcut. Perhaps it would be safest to create a function with this code and put the function call in the button.

Comment: good point, this is an issue for all shortcuts. Also it might be better to wrap the code in a try/catch statement (to avoid errors in older releases or when Java is disabled)

Comment: thanks, it works at command window, is it possible to do the same thing at help window? I tried, it not works.

Comment: @HaveF: no, the code only works for the command window..

Comment: @Amro en, my question is closed...I don't know how to reopen it for "help window"

Answer (score 0):

It is not very nice as it is an external solution, but this is how it could work:

Assuming you are in the command window and want to evaluate size(var_a) by selecting it, you can probably do this with a keyboard macro. Defind the appropriate function of var_a

```
f(x) = eval('size(' x ')'
```

%This could be done in the macro, but nicer to do it here for easy editing.

Then make sure your macro does this:

```
Copy 'var_a'
Turn it into 'f(var_a)'
Paste the result
Hit enter
```

Like i said, it's not pretty, but it should do the trick.